# how to hide all li tags that are nested under level 2 using css

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I just display the first level li tags and hide the rest using CSS? This way we only see the first level tiles and the second/third level tiles are hidden. Just to be clear, the idea is to next, make it cascading friendly using jQuery but one thing at a time :) Please find my code embedded here...

Let me know if you have any question at all..

```css
.chartArea {
  padding: 20px 20px 0 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  color: white;
}

.tile {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  font-family: segoe UI;
  color: white;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.empDetails {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid chartArea">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="tile">Adam</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tile">
        <div class="col-sm-2 img_tile">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 empDetails">
          <h4>
              Lily
            </h4>
          <p>
            Director
          </p>
          <p>
            Ensure quality and timely delivery through resource and time management.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 toggle_button">
          <a class="menu-toggle" href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="tile">
            <div class="col-sm-2 img_tile">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 empDetails">
              <h4>
              Sen
            </h4>
              <p>
                Manager
              </p>
              <p>
                Ensure quality and timely delivery through resource and time management.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="tile">Another Sen</div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="tile">Sen jr</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="tile">Justin</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a container `div` defined you must use the container class to target specific levels using `>` operator, adding these two classes will do the work for you `.chartArea ul li` will hide all levels `li` and `.chartArea > ul > li {` will affect only the first level.

```
.chartArea ul li
{
  display: none;
}

.chartArea > ul > li {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
.chartArea {
  padding: 20px 20px 0 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  color: white;
}

.tile {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  font-family: segoe UI;
  color: white;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.empDetails {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
}

.chartArea ul li {
  display: none;
}

.chartArea>ul>li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid chartArea">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="tile">Adam</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tile">
        <div class="col-sm-2 img_tile">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 empDetails">
          <h4>
            Lily
          </h4>
          <p>
            Director
          </p>
          <p>
            Ensure quality and timely delivery through resource and time management.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 toggle_button">
          <a class="menu-toggle" href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="tile">
            <div class="col-sm-2 img_tile">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 empDetails">
              <h4>
                Sen
              </h4>
              <p>
                Manager
              </p>
              <p>
                Ensure quality and timely delivery through resource and time management.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="tile">Another Sen</div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="tile">Sen jr</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="tile">Justin</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Cleaner shorter answer. Appreciate it!

Comment: glad it helped you out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the CSS **[child combinator (`>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)**.

Specifying `li > ul > li` will target any `li` elements that are at the grandchildren of `<li>` elements themselves. **However**, note that this will also work for **subsequent** `<li>` grandchildren (great-great-grandchildren of the initial `<li>` element).

You can prevent this by making use of `.chartArea` directly, with 
  `.chartArea >  ul > li > ul > li`. While not stricly necessary (if you only hide the grandchildren, the great-great grandchildren will be hidden as well), it's better to be **[more specific](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**. This is because if you were to make use of `visibility: hidden` rather than `display: none`, the great-great-grandchildren would still retain DOM flow.

As such, you're looking for:

```
.chartArea >  ul > li > ul > li {
  display: none;
}
```

Which can be seen in the following:

```css
.chartArea {
  padding: 20px 20px 0 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  color: white;
}

.tile {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  font-family: segoe UI;
  color: white;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.empDetails {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: block;
}

.chartArea>ul>li>ul>li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid chartArea">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="tile">Adam</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tile">
        <div class="col-sm-2 img_tile">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 empDetails">
          <h4>
            Lily
          </h4>
          <p>
            Director
          </p>
          <p>
            Ensure quality and timely delivery through resource and time management.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 toggle_button">
          <a class="menu-toggle" href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="tile">
            <div class="col-sm-2 img_tile">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 empDetails">
              <h4>
                Sen
              </h4>
              <p>
                Manager
              </p>
              <p>
                Ensure quality and timely delivery through resource and time management.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="tile">Another Sen</div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="tile">Sen jr</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="tile">Justin</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)